# How to convert range to string in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, custom-function

I have a script in Google Spreadsheet that counts how many cells of specified colors are in the range (for example 10 cells in a range and 3 of them have a red font).

```
function countTextColor(inputRangeStr, inputColorStr) {
  var inputRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(inputRangeStr);
    . . . 
    . . . 
}
```

If I call the function where the range is as a string, then there's no problem:

```
=COUNTTEXTCOLOR("A1:F1", "#ff0000")
```

But I need to use the range as a real reference where it dynamically points to the specified cells. When calling it like this...

```
=COUNTTEXTCOLOR(A1:F1, "#ff0000")
```

... it returns Exception:

```
Range not found (line 9).
```

I understand that the reference needs to be converted to a string format but how to do that?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58179/192251 - basically, passing the dynamic range to your function passes a 2-dimensional array of the cell *values*, so you can't easily get the actual range string from there (unless you explicitly pass a string "A1:F1" as you mentioned)

Comment: @Blundering **It can be done**. See other answer in [your post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92156)

Answer (score 0):

- In Apps Script any value that is not strictly numeric must be a string
- A string cannot be passed without quotes

### As a workaround:

- Save the real references without quotes in a separate column (e.g. column I)
- Call you Apps Script with `=COUNTTEXTCOLOR(TO_TEXT(I1), "#ff0000")` - this will convert your range notation to a string

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to pass two parameters for the range. one as range like A1:B2 just to trigger function and one as string like "A1:B2" which will be actually used inside function.

So function call will look like this

```
=myFunction(A1:B2, "A1:B2")
```

And function declaration:

```
function myFunction(range, rangeStr) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cells = sheet.getRange(rangeStr);

  // do your job here
}
```